# Mysql column comparison 'different from 0' but not from NULL

Tags: mysql

If I select a column from a MYSQL column, I try to check if it's different from zero (0) by the following constraint:

```
WHERE my_column_name <> 0
```

It returns false if it's zero (0) but also if it's NULL. And that's not the purpose.

How do I have to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` - safe comparison is done with `<=>`, [you only need to add a NOT()](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73860f/2) as an alternative:

```
   WHERE NOT(my_column_name <=> 0)
```